# Devextreme: Custom dxTemplate and <table(s)> with static header row

Tags: html, knockout.js, devexpress, phonejs, devextreme

I'm trying to create a dynamically filled table using knockoutJS/DevExtreme but I'm having trouble with my header row. If I put the template line as an attribute of a holding div like this  and then nestle the table underneath all is good except my header row repeats itself for every entry.

What I'm trying to do is have a 'static' (for want of a better word) header row and half the other rows get created from the template like so:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Project</th>
    <th>Cost Centre</th>
  </tr>
  <tr data-options="dxTemplate:{ name:'item' }">
    <td data-bind="text: dateTime"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: projectName"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: costCenterName"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this while using devExpress? Or alternatively, feel free to show me what is probably obviously the correct and far easier way to do things...

Thanks in advance

Edit... inspecting one of the blank table rows has given me the following

```
<div data-bind="css:{ 'dx-state-disabled': $data.disabled, 'dx-state-invisible': !$data.visible &amp;&amp; $data.visible !== undefined }" class="dx-list-item"><!-- ko if: $data.html && !$data.text --><!-- /ko --><!-- ko if: !$data.html && $data.text --><!-- /ko --><!-- ko ifnot: $.isPlainObject($data) --><!-- /ko --><!-- ko if: $data.key --><!-- /ko --></div>
<!-- ko if: $data.html && !$data.text -->
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: !$data.html && $data.text -->
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: $.isPlainObject($data) -->
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: $data.key -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Can you put more of your code? (the div tag as well)

Comment: @FlaviaObreja - will post back on monday, code is in office!

Comment: @FlaviaObreja update: issue resolved (as in there is no solution, tables and devextreme don't work). Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with devExpres, but I think it would be useful to use the following table structure:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Project</th>
       <th>Cost Centre</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-options="dxTemplate:{ name:'item' }">
    <tr>
       <td data-bind="text: dateTime"></td>
       <td data-bind="text: projectName"></td>
       <td data-bind="text: costCenterName"></td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```